# @Controller , @RestController and @Component not working in child package in Spring boot multi module maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

**Parent POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sit</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>one</module>
    <module>app</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>multi-module</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**app module POM**

spring boot main class resides on this module

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sit</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>app</artifactId>


   <dependencies>


   </dependencies>

</project>
```

**One module (child module) POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sit</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>one</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Spring Boot Main Class from **app module**

```
package com.sit.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sit"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.sit"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }

}
```

AppController from **app module**

```
package com.sit.app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class AppController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/app")
    public String getPage(){
        return "app";
    }
}
```

OneController class from **one module**

```
package com.sit.one.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;



@Controller
public class OneController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/one")
    public String getPage(){
        return "one";
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the project structure]

When I run the project AppController.java is working fine by "/app" url.But when I try to access  "/one" url of OneController.java  ,I got the error page.No @Controller or @RestController is working from child (one)  module.To solve this issue  I added @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sit"}) in Application.java, but still I am getting the error page.Can any help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand the project structure, but shouldn't you add a dependency to the `one` module within the `app` module? Otherwise those classes won't be added to the classpath.

Comment: as your structure is not completely clear , Please check your project structure with https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-custom-starter/greeter-spring-boot-starter/pom.xml

Comment: Do you mean dependency of "app"  inside "one" module ?  @- g00glen00b

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun I clarified my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `com.sit:one` is not on the classpath of `com.sit:app`. Due to this, none of the classes of the **one module** can be found when you start the **application module**.

The solution is to make sure that the `com.sit:one` module is a dependency of `com.sit:app` by adding the following to `pom.xml` of the **application module**:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>one</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However, this is not enough, since the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` will create a fat JAR of both modules, while you only need a fat JAR of your **application module** (the runnable module).

I suggest that you move the `<plugin>` to the `pom.xml` of the **application module**:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

And then you should remove the plugin from the parent `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks g00glen00b it woks.